# When the asynctasks that fill ArrayList are finished I want work with ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist

There is my code of course I removes some unimportant parts. Here are 3 class with extends AsyncTask. LoadAllProducts execute three DownloadTask and every DownloadTask execute ParserTask and ParserTask fill ArrayList. After all is finished I want wark with arrayList.

```
public class MapActivity extends FragmentActivity {
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;
        DownloadTask downloadTask;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.map_layout);
            dists = new ArrayList<String>();
            // Loading products in Background Thread
            new LoadAllProducts().execute();
     }
```

....and here i want work with arrayList dists after fill.....

```
    // Fetches data from url passed
    private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
    {
        // Downloading data in non-ui thread
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url){}

        // Executes in UI thread, after the execution of doInBackground()
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result){
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            parserTask.execute(result);
        }
    }

    /** A class to parse the Google Places in JSON format */
    private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<List<HashMap<String, String>>>>{
      // Parsing the data in non-ui thread
        @Override
        protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(String... jsonData){
        }

        // Executes in UI thread, after the parsing process
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result){
            //here is arrayList filled
            dists.add(result);
        }
    }
    /**
     * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
     * */
    class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MapActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage(".....");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * getting All products from url
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            return null;
        }
        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
             for(int i; i < 3; i++){
                downloadTask = new DownloadTask();
                downloadTask.execute(result);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: I dont know if all ParserTask are finished. And if they are not finished in arrayList are not all results.

Comment: you can use Threads .... for that study wait and notify .. create a main thread that will wait for all the threads to complete their task and when they complete their tasks main thread will be notified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just call a method of your activity in onPostExecute of the last asyncTask to run.

```
public class MapActivity extends FragmentActivity {


    boolean areTasksComplete = false;
    //call this when last task is complete
    public void afterAllTasksComplete(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result) {
        areTasksComplete = true;
        dists.add(result);

    }

    private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
    {
        // Downloading data in non-ui thread
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url){}

        // Executes in UI thread, after the execution of doInBackground()
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result){
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            parserTask.execute(result);
        }
    }

    /** A class to parse the Google Places in JSON format */
    private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<List<HashMap<String, String>>>>{
      // Parsing the data in non-ui thread
        @Override
        protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(String... jsonData){
        }

        // Executes in UI thread, after the parsing process
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result){

            afterAllTasksComplete(result);
        }
    }
    /**
     * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
     * */
    class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        //.....//

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
             for(int i; i < 3; i++){
                downloadTask = new DownloadTask();
                downloadTask.execute(result);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Also, there is a library called BoltsFramework which makes chaining asynchronous work easier.
https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-Android

Answer (score 0):

You should try using [onPostExecute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute%28Result%29).

Technically speaking, there is no built in mechanism to check if all tasks are finished, so you could just try checking every so often if one task is finished, if it's done, check the other and so on, while resetting the mechanism if any of them aren't finished.

In simpler words -- check every so often, until everything is done.